# how to store multiple key value pairs in shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have  username and password field I want to store them using shared preferences.please guide me in storing and retrieving these data using sharedpreferences.

```
       sharedPref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String secretKey = sharedPref.getString("imei_num", null);
                    if(null==secretKey){
                        editor.putString("imei_num",imei_of_the_device);
                        editor.putString("pin",pinPrimary.getText().toString());
                        editor.commit(); 



                    }
```

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: i edited the question.included the code

Comment: do you need to save multiple pair of user name and password.

Comment: No just a single pair.And I want if its stored once it should not stored again.

Comment: what kind difficult you are facing?

Comment: Actually I was creating a login module using (IMEI+a Pin Fetched from Server).I wanted that if a user is logged in once than he/she should not log in again and again so I wanted to use login like this if the data about login is already present then user dont need to login again but user will directly go to MainActivity.

Comment: No more how do I make an unsecure app questions.  IE how do I store user/password.  Something like how do I store user/nickname would get you the same answers as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store in SharedPreferences :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedf",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("imei_num",imei_of_the_device)
.putString("pin",pinPrimary.getText().toString()).commit();
```

And retrieve like this :

```
String imei = prefs.getString("imei_num", "default value");
String pass = prefs.getString("pin", "default value");
```

Comment: I am sorry but what is default value?

Comment: It's the value to return if there is no key in your sharedPrefs named "imei_num" or "pass"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prefs.getString("key","default")` retrieve value saved for given key if the key is not found it will return default value instead of `null`